# Windows Batch File to call PHP Script

Tags: windows, batch-file, image-uploading

Can somebody please explain what is this batch file trying to do

```
setlocal
SET tmpfile="temp3.txt"

for %%f in (FY2?_20??.JPG) do (
    curl --form image=@%%f http://www.test.com/images/image_upload.php>%tmpfile%

    REN "%%f" "DONE-%%f"
    REN %tmpfile% "%%f.log"
 )
```

thank you for your any help and suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All it does is upload a bunch of images that match a certain filename mask to a remote server and stores the curl output in a log file, then renames those images when they've been processed.

But since that answer is short and boring, I'll go through the script line by line.

---

```
setlocal
```

Sandboxes the variables that get set in the script so that they can't be accessed once the script ends. Not necessary, but good practice.

```
SET tmpfile="temp3.txt"
```

Sets a variable called `tmpfile` to the value `temp3.txt`.

```
for %%f in (FY2?_20??.JPG) do (
```

Iterates over the list of every JPG file in the current directory that starts with `FY2`, then some character, then `_20`, then two more characters.

```
    curl --form image=@%%f http://www.test.com/images/image_upload.php>%tmpfile%
```

Uploads each image to www.test.com via that site's image_upload.php page. The output of the `curl` command gets redirected to the file whose location got stored in the `%tmpfile%` variable earlier. `>` says to overwrite the contents of the file or create a new file if one does not exist. The `--form` option makes `curl` send the image via POST rather than GET.

```
    REN "%%f" "DONE-%%f"
```

Appends the string "DONE-" in front of the current file name

```
    REN %tmpfile% "%%f.log"
```

Changes the name of the log file to match the name of the file that was just uploaded. This line tells me that the `%tmpfile%` variable is redundant and the `curl` output could simply have been redirected to `%%f.log` without needing a temporary file.

```
 )
```

This just closes the `for` loop.

Comment: curl --form image=@%%f http://www.test.com/images/image_upload.php>%tmpfile%
Is this line send file information by post method to image_upload.php ?

Comment: That is correct. Each line of code has its description written below it.

Comment: last one are you sure "for %%f in (FY2?_20??.JPG) do (" 
this will look for currrent directory %%f what does this mean?

Comment: I am positive. When the `for` loop iterates through the list of JPG files, it does so one at a time. `%%f` is the file that the loop is currently looking at.